# Apps available? Nutrition Help?

Tags: nutrition

I know there are a ton of apps available that track your nutrition and general overall health, but I am having trouble in figuring out what to eat at home to be healthy and what to even buy to make those said meals.

Answer (score 1):

Although probably not the answer you are looking for I would suggest starting with learning basic understandings of macro nutrients e.g. [carbs, fats and proteins](http://study.com/academy/lesson/what-are-macronutrients-definition-functions-examples.html)

Once learning that making meals of very simple foods e.g. vegtables + chicken and then weighing and entering them in apps like myfitnesspal.com and seeing the macronutrients used up compared to [how much you need](http://www.iifym.com/iifym-calculator/).

from these basic meals you can start experimenting with extra ingredients to make things taste better and entering them in to the apps as well to see the effects. e.g. spices, oil, sauces etc.

Doing this took a while but taught me a lot about nutrition and eventually you get to the point where you can judge foods on face value accurately.

hope this helps